# How to get the row values of gridview

Tags: jquery, templates, gridview

Am working on a certain requirement.... it has a gridview with a item template  in which when I click on the button inside the gridview it show popup page which shows certain details with respect to the parentwindow's---->gridview's---->template field's---> id(column).

This above should be done with jquery

1. how to get the row value of the gridview  using jquery
2. how to pass the querystring to the popup page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="a_link" id='<%# Eval("Id") %>' name='<%# Eval("Name") %>' onclick="javascript:return ShowDetails(this);">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label></a>
               </ItemTemplate>                    
           </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function ShowDetails(obj) {
           var id=$(obj).attr("id");
           var name=$(obj).attr("name");
           return false;
   }
 });
```